# Why can't I bind the WPFToolkit DataGrid ItemSource to DataTable?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid, telerik, wpftoolkit

In a `Telerik` control, I was able to bind a `DataTable` directly to the `ItemSource`, but when I switched to the Codeplex `WPFToolkit` `Datagrid`:

```
<dg:DataGrid Name="theGrid"/>
---
theGrid.ItemsSource = dt;
```

I get this error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataTable' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'.
```

How can I bind the `DataTable` to the`WPFToolkit` `DataGrid`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to project your datatable into something that implements IEnumerable as that is waht the DataGrid expects.  The grid is a different implementation to the Telerik version so its hard to expect the same functionality from both.

Comment: This worked, in fact I was converting from an List<Contact> to the Datatable for the Telerik control so this is even easier, I just use the original List<Contact> object now, thanks.

Answer (score 32):

I find the easiest way is:

```
myDataGrid.ItemsSource = myDataTable.DefaultView;
```

because DefaultView implements IEnumerable

Comment: +1, binding to a DataView is simple and works great, especially if you want to be able to navigate relations.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming support for this will be added in the future, but for now you can use the implementation of `IListSource` on `DataTable`. Call the `GetList()` method and use that as your data source. It's an explicit interface implementation so you'll need to cast:

```
var data = (myDataTable as IListSource).GetList();
```

Comment: I found this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa325664(VS.71).aspx but how do I use the implementation of IListSource on DataTable in order to call the GetList() method?

Answer (score 0):

In such cases I bind ItemsSource to DataContex in XAML i.e.

```
ItemsSource={Binding}
```

and then in codebehind I do

```
theGrid.DataContext = dt
```

This will help.