# How to load a datatable into wpf data grid

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to display the content of a datatable in my wpf datagrid

In the following post:

[Why can't I bind the WPFToolkit DataGrid ItemSource to DataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502667/why-cant-i-bind-the-wpftoolkit-datagrid-itemsource-to-datatable)

I found the code:

```
myDataGrid.ItemsSource = myDataTable.DefaultView;
```

and the behaviour is strange: it shows n empty rows where the n is correct: the query results n rows!

So why can't I see them?

Comment: Is the DataGrid autogenerating the columns?

Comment: +1 yes I already found it...  myGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = true; that indeed was the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing the code, I would guess that you don't have `AutoGenerateColumns` set to to true.  That's fine, but if you aren't auto-generating columns, you need to manually add column definitions to your data grid.

Answer (score -2):

One possible solution would be to replace the `DataGrid` with a [`DataGridView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx) and bind the `DataGridView.DataSource` property to the `DataTable` itself.  As per [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.defaultview.aspx):

`dataGrid1.DataSource = table;`

Comment: We are talking about WPF. DataGridView is a WinForms control.