# Displaying data table in C# WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am writing a WPF application in C# that needs to display data in a spreadsheet-like format dynamically.  What is the best way to go about this?

The application will be getting data outputted from a fire alarm panel, chopping it up, and then displaying it in a neat table (or at least that's the plan).

Comment: Duplicate? Here's some more detailed info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134300/how-to-load-a-datatable-into-wpf-data-grid

Answer (score 16):

Why not use WPF's Datagrid control?  It should have all the functionality you need for the requirements you posted, more info here

http://www.wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html

Answer (score 3):

If you are using .Net 3.5, then please download [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/) and install to your VS 2008.

If you are using .Net 4.0, you can use the build in DataGrid control which you can select from the toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

i think you might try to use using. Graham Knight is developing a lightweight, high performance data grid for WPF. This data grid, known as WPF Table View, is available on CodePlex under the Microsoft Public License.
It's able to view 100,000+ rows of data with dynamically defined columns and column data templates, as soon as I threw this at the data grid the user experience began to suffer.
http://tableview.codeplex.com/